# How do I execute a SectionedFetchRequest in a SwiftUI Preview?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Previously, I was using `FetchRequest` and passing the results to my view. I had this working in my preview using the following code:

```
struct SchoolsGrid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    static var fetchRequest = School.fetchRequest()

    static func getSchools() -> [School] {
        do {
            return try viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return []
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        SchoolsGrid(sectionedSchools: Dictionary(
            grouping: getSchools(),
            by: {
                $0.name!.first!.isLetter ? String($0.name!.first!) : "#"
            }
        ))
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
        .environmentObject(SettingsData())
    }
}
```

After learning about `SectionedFetchRequest`, I updated my code and my view to accept this instead, but I am unable to find the "sectioned" alternative to the code above. I tried the following without any luck - it returns no data:

```
struct SchoolsGrid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    static var fetchRequest = SectionedFetchRequest(fetchRequest: School.fetchRequest(), sectionIdentifier: \School.firstLetterOfName)

    static var previews: some View {
        SchoolsGrid(sectionedSchools: fetchRequest.wrappedValue)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
            .environmentObject(SettingsData())
    }
}
```

---

**Edit to add:**

I have a wrapper view which fetches my data, because the same data can be presented in two different subviews - SchoolsGrid and SchoolsList:

```
struct Schools: View {
    @State var isGrid = false
    @State var searchTerm: String = ""

    @SectionedFetchRequest<String, School>(
        entity: School.entity(),
        sectionIdentifier: \.firstLetterOfName,
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \School.name, ascending: true),
        ]
    ) var sectionedSchools: SectionedFetchResults<String, School>

    var query: Binding<String> {
        Binding {
            searchTerm
        } set: { newValue in
            searchTerm = newValue
            let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", #keyPath(School.name), newValue)
            sectionedSchools.nsPredicate = newValue.isEmpty
                ? nil
                : namePredicate
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollViewReader { _ in
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        if isGrid {
                            SchoolsGrid(sectionedSchools: sectionedSchools, searchTerm: searchTerm)
                        } else {
                            SchoolsList(sectionedSchools: sectionedSchools, searchTerm: searchTerm)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .searchable(text: query)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Schools")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: { isGrid.toggle() }) {
                        Image(systemName: isGrid ? "list.bullet" : "square.grid.2x2")
                            .accessibilityLabel("Toggle View")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My SchoolsGrid looks like:

```
struct SchoolsGrid: View {
    var sectionedSchools: SectionedFetchResults<String, School>
    var searchTerm: String

    var gridItems: [GridItem] {
        Array(repeating: .init(.adaptive(minimum: 120)), count: 2)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(sectionedSchools) { section in
                Section(header: SchoolsGridSectionHeader(key: section.id)) {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems) {
                        ForEach(section) { school in
                            NavigationLink(destination: SchoolDetail(school: school)) {
                                SchoolsGridItem(school: school, searchTerm: searchTerm)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my SchoolsList:

```
struct SchoolsList: View {
    var sectionedSchools: SectionedFetchResults<String, School>
    var searchTerm: String

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(sectionedSchools) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section.id).id(section.id)) {
                    ForEach(section) { school in
                        NavigationLink(destination: SchoolDetail(school: school)) {
                            SchoolsListItem(school: school, searchTerm: searchTerm)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

As with the first part of my question, I only recently changed the fetch request to a sectioned fetch request, so previously both `SchoolsGrid` and `SchoolsList` accepted `schools: FetchResults< School>` and I was able to emulate this in the Preview using the first code block, where I used `viewContext.fetch`. After updating to accept `sectionedSchools: SectionedFetchResults<String, School>`, there is no `viewContext.sectionedFetch` that I can use, so passing it the way I tried using:

`var fetchRequest = SectionedFetchRequest(fetchRequest: School.fetchRequest(), sectionIdentifier: \School.firstLetterOfName)`

returns no data because it isn't being called on the preview view context.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017

Comment: The problem here is that my view accepts the SectionedFetchResults as a variable, so the preview needs to execute the fetch request so that I can pass the results down. Previously I would do `viewContext.fetch()` but there seems to be no `viewContext.sectionedFetch` alternative.

Comment: You shouldn't need anything extra for SectionedFetchRequest, it's your handling of FetchRequest that looks odd to me.

Comment: Would you happen to have any advice on how I can improve it?

Comment: `SectionedFetchRequest` is by [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/SectionedFetchRequest) a property wrapper. You should implement it as such. It is hard to help when all the extra work does not seem warranted. Like I sad before without a full example we can't help you troubleshoot your ultimate goal. It seems like you are just fighting SwiftUI for the sake of fighting.

Comment: I've updated my post with the relevant code to explain what I am trying to achieve. Appreciate the time.